# How to get border around image

Tags: html, css, xhtml, lightbox

Hi there I'am playing around with light box. What I am trying to do is get a border around my thumbnail so that when the user hovers over it, it will change color.

Example : http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

You can see when you hover the thumbnail it changes the border color around the image. Can anyone help me do this with my images? I have put them around in a div and i got 6 of them. Thanks for the help.

Html:

```
<div class = "lightbox">
    <a href="images/image1.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image1t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image2.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image2t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image3.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image3t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image4.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image4t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image5.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image5t.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/image6.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]"><img src="images/image6t.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
a img
{
border:3px solid #ccc;
}
a:hover img
{
border:3px solid #666;
}
```

for better example check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBpd4/3/)

Comment: Best answer worked like a treat. Quick question if you could those how do i make it so its like spread out a bit? i think it ssomething to do with margin or padding? not 2 sure those

Comment: im not sure if i got you right, but you can achieve that by increasing the border size. Or if you want some space between the border and the image then ill edit my answer.

Comment: ah ok and quick question i got something else which is using the a tag which changes that, how do i change this ? like i put it all in the div called lightbox but not sure how 2 change it

Comment: i edited the answer, take a look. Also if this answers you question, please mark it as answer. :)

Comment: ah thanks but it still messes around with my navgation bar. Not sure why

Comment: i updated the fiddle, please take a look. Also, can you tell me what is messed up with your navigation?

Comment: here is the question , thanks again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800054/navigation-bar-messing-with-other-elments-in-css#

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a border, just add some `padding` and a `background-color` to the anchor. Then change it's color on `:hover`

Comment: this will get you in trouble when you ever decide to use transparent png's. I would suggest adding some padding to the `a`, and also applying the border to the `a`. Why use a background hack if you want to achieve a border in the first place?